# Probability of intersection bigger than 0

Tags: probability

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and two events $A$ and $B$. How do I show that
$$P(A\cap B)>0\Rightarrow P(B)>0?$$

Comment: If $P(B)=0$, then $0<P(A\cap B)\leq P(B)=0$ a contradiction.

Comment: Do you know that probability is monotone? $A \cap B$ is clearly smaller than $B$, so it has smaller probability.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb P(B) = \mathbb P(B \cap A) + \mathbb P(B \cap A^c)$ since the sets involved on the right hand side are disjoint and their union is $B$.